# Cannot print pdf using wkhtmltopdf and php wrapper

Tags: php, windows, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to print a PDF using wkhtmltopdf and this wrapper https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf

I installed wkhtmltopdf in C:\wkhtmltopdf, and works(I can print pdf using the command line) but if i try using the wrapper the only thing I get it's a blank page in my browser and 'Could not create PDF: Could not run command "C:\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe"' in my logs.

this is my code:

```
include("wkhtmltopdf.php");
$mipdf = new WkHtmlToPdf(array(
            // Use `wkhtmltopdf-i386` or `wkhtmltopdf-amd64`
            'binPath' => 'C:\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
        ));
$mipdf ->addPage('http://google.com');
$mipdf ->send('test.pdf');
```

I tried everything but i can't make this thing work.

Can somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Have you installed wkhtmltopdf into C:\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe? That's not the default path for installation, that's why I'm asking (although I use that path).

Comment: yes, i installed it there. the path(C:\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe) works beacause when i use the cmd i can print a pdf. i'm using win xp(i don't know if this can change something). I tried installing wkhtmltopdf in another path and i still get the "Could not create PDF: Could not run command....."(note: my default path is C:\wkhtmltopdf\ , ask windows why)